# git log command to get the formatted output

Tags: git, github

I would like to get the below details from git using the commit id in single line,

i.e oldblobid, newblobid, linesadded, linesdeleted, mod type (M,A,D) , file path

I am using the following command but it gives some other details and also it provides in different lines, so the parsing of this data is bit complicated,

**Command used :**

```
git log -1 -m --pretty=format: --raw --pretty="%P" --numstat commitId
```

This returns the output as below,

**Current Output:**

```
:150644 150644 77334b8 c113e7f M        src/fs1       <-- shows in multiple lines part 1

:150644 150644 46334b8 341363f M        src/fs2


5       3      src/fs1                                <-- shows in multiple lines part 2

2       1       src/fs2
```

But is there any way to get the output like below,

**Expected Output:**

```
oldblobid   newblobid   modtype   linesadd   linesdel   filepath  

77334b8   c113e7f     M        5         3     src/fs1   <-- expecting output in one line with all details

46334b8   341363f     M        2         1     src/fs2
```

Please let me know if any other command to get the output like this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any suggestions? please let me know.

Comment: Hi Team,    Is there any solution for this request?